# How to catch an event when the user starts typing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an input box with an inline *cross* icon. The job of that icon is to clear the input box when clicked. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Now, having this icon visible when there's no text in the input box as shown in the picture doesn't make any sense. Ideally, the right thing to do would be to keep it hidden and show it only once the user starts typing something inside of the box. How do I catch that particular event (of the user starting to type)? I am aware of `oninput()` but the problem is, it fires every time anything is typed. So if you type, say, "wiki," it will fire 4 times! I need something that fires only once when you type the first letter. Is it even possible?

Another alternative I can think of is to have a function watch the input box value and fire up the moment it's no longer empty. Something like this:

```
var check = document.getElementById('word').value;
if(check != ""){
  // show "delete" icon
}
```

But in this case, how can I ensure the function does trigger, i.e. it's always on the lookout for the input box value change? Would it help to place the above snippet inside an anonymous function and leave it at that?

Comment: why you want it only fires once on first letter? any reason?

Comment: just check for the length of input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide icons by default

```
 $('#check').on('input', function() {
  if($(this).val() != '') {
    //Write show() function for icon selectors
  } else {
    // Write hide() function for icon selectors
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way.

```
$("#textbox").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length>0){
        $("#clearicon").show();
    }
    else
    {
         $("#clearicon").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not fire it just once because otherwise if the user deletes the content of the input text you would still be showing the button. Instead you can do:

```
document.getElementById('itext').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (e.target.value !== '') {
    console.log('show button');
  }
  else {
    console.log('hide button');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textbox").keydown(function(e){
   //  show "delete" icon
});
```

Comment: Again, won't this fire after every single letter being typed? I need the function to trigger only when the user "starts" typing.

Comment: If you want to show that icon when users type what about 'focus' and 'focusout' when user focus on that box icon will showup.

Comment: focus is not the same as typing. I don't need the icon up until the user actually starts typing.

Comment: If the user deletes the content of the input you should not show the button anymore. So fire it just once is not the best solution.

Comment: @felipe-t Delete button is tigger this event too. you can check length of content.

Comment: I agree @Kichnipan. My comment was intended to the author of the question. Though, I would not use the keydown event because probably will fire with unnecessary keys.

Comment: @felipe-t Oh I'm sorry, How about use 'keydown' to show icon and 'focusout' to remove icon ??

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use keydown event and check value of input every time whether it is empty or not if its value is empty then hide the delete icon else show it.

$("#textbox").keydown(function(e){
   if($("textbox").val()==null || $("textbox").val()=="")
   {
     $("deleteIcon").hide();
   }
});
```